# Missing Result tab in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I'm looking for the 'Result' tab mentionned in [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On Test Manager 2013, I set a test plan, and performed my tests. I now want to share the results.

Basically, I should have:

Plan =>
  Contents | Results | Properties

But I only have:

Plan => 
  Contents | Properties

[image]

Is there a TFS configuration for this? Any idea on what's wrong?

Here the version I run:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I just added a snapshot, thanks

Comment: Can you ensure that you're opening the 2013 version of MTM? I'm also not seeing the "Open in Web Access" button that should be on the same level as where you see "New" and "Add Requirements" button

Comment: Well, it seems that I missed an update, install in progress...

Comment: No luck with the update. Is it meaningful that I'm connecting to a TFS 2010 server?

Comment: Yes, it is meaningful. This pane only appears when connecting to a TFS 2012 server.